# OpenShift 4 domain change

Tags: dns, openshift, openshift-4

We already have an OpenShift 4 cluster installed, setup and filled with some content, but the domain of the company has changed.
If I'm right, the domain of OpenShift 4 cannot be updated by definition.
So what are my possibilities to use the new domain instead of the old one?
Should I delete, reinstall the cluster and make a migration somehow (how?), or is there any possibility to change the base domain of the whole cluster?

Thx,
Peti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how "deep" you want to go to "rename" your cluster, if it is enough to have your apps to listen to the new domain name, you could simply add another ingress controller that will listen on your new domain name, given that te new domain name is known to the DNS

[Doc on ingress controller is here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/networking/ingress-operator.html)

Also migrating from one cluster to another can be done by installing the migration operator (based on velero)

[Doc on migration tool here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/migration/migrating_4_2_4/migrating-application-workloads-4-2-4.html)

Answer (score 2):

As you know, the OCP4 cannot change the base domain after installation due to referred certificates CN and initial configurations depended on base domain. First of all, I suggest you to ask for RH supports whether you can create additional cluster for migration or not. Then usually, you may migrate your current system to new cluster installed with new base domain through provided migration tool. Refer [Migration tools and prerequisites](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/migration/migrating_4_2_4/migrating-application-workloads-4-2-4.html) for more details.